# Segmentation Fault on fclose

Tags: c, linux

I am getting Segmentation fault error while running program in Linux. Working fine in AIX.

And I get a seg fault with the message in gdb...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault 
fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6

```
            <pre><code>
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<string.h>
            #include<unistd.h>
            #include<time.h>
            #include<sys/types.h>
            #define _Monthly "99992016"


            FILE *source,*list,*wlist,*movlist,*biflis;
            char sf[85],sf1[85];
            char filename[85],filename1[85],name[140],fstring[140],iname[140],account[85];
            char *ptr="",*st="";
            int i,len,x,y,z,BIF_COUNT,PIN_COUNT,YOUR_MONTHLY_COUNT,count1,count2;
            char suffix[4]=".pin";
            char *nptr=" ";
            FILE *biflis;
             int p;
            int main()
            {
            long t;
            system("ls -l|sort -n >test.txt");
            system("cat test.txt|grep BH|awk '$5 <= 1610612736 {print $9}' > bhatia.out");
            system("cat test.txt|grep BH|awk '$5 > 1610612736 {print $9}' > bhatia1.out");     
            if((list=fopen("bhatia.out","r"))==NULL)
            {  printf("\n Error opening bhatia.out\n\n "); return 0; }

             if((biflis=fopen("biffile_account.lis","w"))==NULL)
             {   printf("\n Error opening biffile_account.lis file\n\n");
              return 0; }
            BIF_COUNT=0;
            PIN_COUNT=0;
            YOUR_MONTHLY_COUNT=0;
            count1=0;
            while((fgets(filename,85,list))!=NULL)
            {
                ptr=filename;
             for(i=0;*ptr;i++,ptr++)
             {
              sf[i]=*ptr;
             }i--;
             sf[i]='\0';

             if((source=fopen(sf,"r"))==NULL)
             {
              printf("\nError Opening Source File %s\n",sf);
              return 0;
             }
            fseek(source,0,SEEK_END);
            fseek(source,-90,SEEK_CUR);
             while((fgets(name,140,source))!=NULL)
             {
              st=strstr(name,_Monthly);
             count2=0;
              if(st!=NULL)
              {
            YOUR_MONTHLY_COUNT++;
            strcpy(account," ");
            count2++;
            //sprintf(fstring,"%s~%s",filename1,account);
            }
             count1= count2 + count1;
            }
            fclose(source);
            if( count1 > 0 )
            {
              printf(" %s   GBIF file  has the correct footer    having ",sf,source);
                printf(" %d number of correct bills \n",count1);
            } 
               else
            {
            printf(" %s   GBIF file has the footer missing and have  incorrect bills  \n",sf,source);
            //printf(" %d number of in incorrect bills \n",count1);
            }
                 count1=0;
            BIF_COUNT++;
            } 
            </code></pre>
```

Comment: Please minimize the problematic test case, and format it into something readable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one major bug:

```
printf(" %s   GBIF file  has the correct footer    having ",sf,source);
```

You also need to go through all the variables declared here:

```
FILE *source,*list,*wlist,*movlist,*biflis;
```

Every single one of them needs to have one call to fopen and one call to fclose, or they should be removed. Also you declare `FILE *biflis;` twice.

And there is no need to use global variables at all.

Comment: how can i remove this bug.. printf(" %s   GBIF file  has the correct footer    having ",sf,source);

Comment: @MikeSidhu By activating an utter minimum of effort on your behalf and read that line twice. Does it make sense? Does it do what you intended?